# Match household partners without loop

Tags: r, loops, data.table

I am trying to avoid using a `loop` in my attempt to recode household partners' variable identification.

`hldid` denotes the household while `persid` the person in the household. 
The variable `partner` indicates the `persid` of the partner and `child` indicate if the row is a child.

What is missing from the variable `partner` is the `persid` for both partners.

For instance for `hldid == 1`, the `persid == 1` has a value of `0` for `partner` while it should be `2`.

This is how the data looks like:

```
> test
   hldid persid age sex relresp partner child
1      1      1  26   2       0       0     0
2      1      2  26   1       1       1     0
3      2      1  59   2       0       0     0
4      2      2  64   1       1       1     0
5      3      1  76   2       0       0     0
6      4      1  65   2       0       0     0
7      4      2  64   1       1       1     0
8      5      1  52   2       0       0     0
9      5      2  51   1       1       1     0
10     5      3  20   2      21       0     1
11     5      4  14   2      21       0     1
12     7      1  69   1       0       0     0
13     7      2  70   2       1       1     0
```

I managed to create a quite ugly loop, however it is too slow for the entire dataset.

```
test$partnerREC = test$partner

for(i in 1:13){
  for(j in 1:13){

    if(
      test$hldid[i] == test$hldid[i+1] & # verify if household is the same 
      (test$persid[i] == test$partner[j])
    )

    {
      test$partnerREC[i] = test$persid[j] # put the persid for each partner
    }
  }
}

> test
   hldid persid age sex relresp partner child partnerREC
1      1      1  26   2       0       0     0          2
2      1      2  26   1       1       1     0          1
3      2      1  59   2       0       0     0          2
4      2      2  64   1       1       1     0          1
5      3      1  76   2       0       0     0          0
6      4      1  65   2       0       0     0          2
7      4      2  64   1       1       1     0          1
8      5      1  52   2       0       0     0          2
9      5      2  51   1       1       1     0          1
10     5      3  20   2      21       0     1          0
11     5      4  14   2      21       0     1          0
12     7      1  69   1       0       0     0          2
13     7      2  70   2       1       1     0          1
```

Any idea how I could use `data.table` for solving this?

```
test = structure(list(hldid = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 
7), persid = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2), age = c(26, 
26, 59, 64, 76, 65, 64, 52, 51, 20, 14, 69, 70), sex = c(2, 1, 
2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2), relresp = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 21, 21, 0, 1), partner = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1), child = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```

Comment: In `hldid == 5` only `persid == 2` has a `partner == 1`, the others are zero. What values should `partner` equal to 3 and 4 take? Why are they (`partnerREC`) still zero with your code?

Comment: @RuiBarradas That are children, see also the `child`-column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
library(data.table)  # load the package
setDT(test)          # convert 'test' to a 'data.table'

test[, partnerREC := persid[c(pmin(2,.N):1,rep(0,(pmax(.N,2)-2)))] *
                       (persid %in% 1:2) *
                       (.N != 1)
     , by = hldid][]
```

which gives:

> ```
> > test
>     hldid persid age sex relresp partner child partnerREC
>  1:     1      1  26   2       0       0     0          2
>  2:     1      2  26   1       1       1     0          1
>  3:     2      1  59   2       0       0     0          2
>  4:     2      2  64   1       1       1     0          1
>  5:     3      1  76   2       0       0     0          0
>  6:     4      1  65   2       0       0     0          2
>  7:     4      2  64   1       1       1     0          1
>  8:     5      1  52   2       0       0     0          2
>  9:     5      2  51   1       1       1     0          1
> 10:     5      3  20   2      21       0     1          0
> 11:     5      4  14   2      21       0     1          0
> 12:     7      1  69   1       0       0     0          2
> 13:     7      2  70   2       1       1     0          1
> ```

This solution is based on the assumption (derived from the example data) that only 'persid' 1 & 2 are partners, anything higher are children.

What this does:

- Group by `hldid`
- Change the order of the first two persons in a hould but only when there are more people in a household with
  `persid[c(pmin(2,.N):1,rep(0,(pmax(.N,2)-2)))]` where `pmin` is used to assure that a vector of length 1 is constructed when a household has only one person.
- Multiply that with `(persid %in% 1:2)`to get zores for children.
- Multiply that with `(.N != 1)` to get a value of zero for households of one person.

Comment: I get this error message when running your code on my full sample. `Error in `[.data.frame`(uk83_householdgrid, , `:=`(partner_id, persid[c(pmin(2,  : 
  unused argument (by = hldid)`. Any idea why?

Comment: @giacomo Probably because you haven't converted your data to a *data.table* with `setDT()` as showed at the beginning of my answer.

Comment: Thanks it works very well, it is a really cool line of code. Could you break down for me a little more this `persid[c(pmin(2,.N):1,rep(0,(pmax(.N,2)-2)))]`, I am not sure I get it completely. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(data = NA, ncol = 7))
names(df) <- names(test)

for(id in unique(test$hldid)){
  t <- test[test$hldid==id,]
  t$partner[t$persid == t$partner[t$partner!=0]] <- t$persid[which(t$partner!=0)]

  df <- rbind(df, t)
}

df <- df[-1,]
```

Comment: Growing objects in a loop isn't considered good coding practise in R. [See here for an example what that does to performance](https://www.r-bloggers.com/growing-objects-and-loop-memory-pre-allocation/).

Answer (score 1):

A base R solution is more complicated than Jaap's `data.table` [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53504608/match-household-partners-without-loop/53505114#53505114).

I work with a copy.

```
test2 <- test
```

After running the code in the question, run the following.

```
test2$partnerREC <- test2$partner
sp <- split(test2, test2$hldid)
test2 <- lapply(sp, function(DF){
  i <- with(DF, which(persid %in% partner))
  j <- with(DF, which(partner %in% persid))
  #cat("i:", i, "\tj:", j, "\n")
  DF$partnerREC[i] <- DF$persid[j]
  DF
})
test2 <- do.call(rbind, test2)
row.names(test2) <- NULL
```

Now compare both results.

```
identical(test, test2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get there through some `dplyr` steps to join the data on itself and update the value of partner when `persid == partner`.

```
test2 <- left_join(test, test %>% select(hldid, persid, partner) %>% filter(partner != 0), by=c("hldid")) %>%
  filter(persid.x == partner.y) %>%
  mutate(partner.x = persid.y)
```

This will give you the head of household with their partner id matched up but you'd have to rejoin this to the original data (I'm not sure the equivalent of SQL `update` in dplyr lingo).

Answer (score 0):

## 1. Create your test data.frame

```
 library(tidyverse)

 test <- tribble(
            ~hldid, ~persid, ~age, ~sex, ~relresp, ~partner, ~child,
             1,      1,     26,   2,       0,       0,         0,
             1,      2,     26,   1,       1,       1,         0,
             2,      1,     59,   2,       0,       0,         0,
             2,      2,     64,   1,       1,       1,         0,
             3,      1,     76,   2,       0,       0,         0,
             4,      1,     65,   2,       0,       0,         0,
             4,      2,     64,   1,       1,       1,         0,
             5,      1,     52,   2,       0,       0,         0,
             5,      2,     51,   1,       1,       1,         0,
             5,      3,     20,   2,      21,       0,         1,
             5,      4,     14,   2,      21,       0,         1,
             7,      1,     69,   1,       0,       0,         0,
             7,      2,     70,   2,       1,       1,         0)
```

## 2. *arrange()*, *group_by()*, and *mutate()* come to rescue

```
test %>%
  # arrange the data in case the raw data did not 
  arrange(hldid, child, persid) %>%
  # group each household 
  group_by(hldid) %>%
  # match first and second household person as each other's partner
  mutate(partnerREC = ifelse(persid == first(persid), nth(persid, 2), first(persid))) %>%
  # correct partnerREC for child and single 
  mutate(partnerREC = ifelse(child == 1 | is.na(partnerREC), 0, partnerREC))
  # un-group it
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 0):

A `loop` solution using `rcpp`

Source the `rcpp` script

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector HHgrid(CharacterVector hid, NumericVector persid, NumericVector partner, 
NumericVector partnerRec) {

  int nrows = hid.size();

  for (int i = 1; i < nrows - 1; i ++){
    for (int j = 0; j < nrows - 1; j++){

      if( (hid(i) == hid(i+1)) & ( persid(i) == partner(j) ) ){
        partnerRec(i) = persid(j); 
      }
    }
    Rcout << i << std::endl;     
  }
  return(partnerRec); 
}
```

and run the function

```
HHgrid(hid = test$hldid, persid = test$persid, partner = test$partner, partnerRec = test$partnerRec)
```

There is just a slight issue with the first case (if you know how to fix it)